# How to calculate annualized rate of return over multiple transactions

Tags: portfolio, transaction, growth

The annual rate of return on an investment can be calculated as 
[image: CAGR of individual investment]

And the top response to [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/4326/calculate-annualized-return-on-stock-with-multiple-transactions) suggests that the return on a portfolio of such purchases is simply the weighted average of returns on individual transactions, where the weighting coefficient is the number of shares bought:

[image: CAGR across portfolio of purchases]

However, by this definition, it seems like the calculated portfolio return can be positive, despite losing money.

Consider the following example: I purchase two shares of stock, one for $100 and one for $10, and sell both for $50, the first held for 1 year and the second held for 0.5 years.

[image]

So I've spent $110 and received $100, but the calculated return is +1175% [ (-50% + 2400%)/2 ].

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1st equation***

```
R = (Pt/Po)^(1/t) - 1
```

annualised returns for shares 1 & 2 are

```
r1 = (50/100) - 1 = -50 %

r2 = (50/10)^(1/0.5) - 1 = 2400 %
```

***2nd equation***

```
R = Sum[mi*Ri]/n
```

Calculating half-year returns corresponding to the holding periods:

"*weighted average of returns on individual transactions*" for each half-year

```
hr1 = (100*(1 + r1)^(1/2) + 10*(1 + r2)^(1/2))/110 - 1 = 9.73698 %

hr2 = (1 + r1)^(1/2) - 1 = -29.2893 %
```

giving the return over the year as

```
(1 + hr1)*(1 + hr2) - 1 = -22.4042 %
```

Comment: Got it, thanks. For a collection of purchases with different holding periods, it looks like this calculation could become quite complex. Is [internal rate of return (IRR)](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/07/internal_rate_return.asp) the best approach in this case?

Comment: Calculation of CAGR is an IRR problem, e.g. `0 = 10 - 50/(1 + r)^0.5` ∴ `r = -50%` but if you mean put all the cash flows in one IRR like so: `0 = 110 - 50/(1 + r)^0.5 - 50/(1 + r)` ∴ `r = -11.875%` you get a quite different result because you are omitting certain information. The closest to reality is a time-weighted return, which you could use if you knew the value of share 1 when you sold share 2. Let's say it was $72.  Then `hr1 = (72 + 50)/(100 + 10) - 1 = 10.9%` and `hr2 = 50/72 - 1 = -30.56%` so `r = (1 + hr1)*(1 + hr2) - 1 = -22.98%`. So the approach in the answer is closer to reality.

Comment: However, if you have numerous transactions IRR (or money-weighted return) is usually a fair enough approximation.  It gets less accurate compared to time-weighted return when there are large mid-period cash flows.